# Install referrer is not received

Tags: java, android

i've placed this in the android manifest:

```
</application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
     <receiver
     android:name="com.erl.aol.BroadcastReceiver"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

this is my java code:

```
    package com.erl.aol.javaReferrerPlugin;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


    public class PluginClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

        static String receivedReferrer = "";
        static String fullPath = "empty";



       @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
            receivedReferrer = referrer;
            fullPath = "full path found";       // do stuff with the referrer
        }

       public static String GetReffererString()
       {
           return receivedReferrer;
       }

       public static String HasEnteredOnReceive()
       {
           return fullPath;
       }

       public static String TestMethod()
       {
           return "This is a test string.";
       }
    }
```

and i try to simulate a broadcast in adb-shell like this:

```
am broadcast -a "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" -n “com.erl.aol/com.erl.aol.javaReferrerPlugin.PluginClass” -e "referrer" "deliveryId=testapp15sep&utm_medium=RANDOM58&utm_source=BroadcastTest"
```

But the command returns :

> Broadcast completed: result=0

And i don't get the referrer on my device. Note that the androidmanifest snippet is just a part of the actual manifest and my app bundle id is

> com.erl.aol

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the correct command is this :
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER --es referrer customReferrer com.erl.aol.javaReferrerPlugin

i'm assuming that your referrer is in the package com.erl.aol.javaReferrerPlugin